# Returning subset of each group from a pandas groupby object

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, multi-level, pandas-loc

I have the multilevel dataframe that looks like:

```
                      date_time      name  note   value
list index                                    
1    0     2015-05-22 05:37:59       Tom   129    False
     1     2015-05-22 05:38:59       Tom     0    True
     2     2015-05-22 05:39:59       Tom     0    False
     3     2015-05-22 05:40:59       Tom    45    True
2    4     2015-05-22 05:37:59       Kate   129    True
     5     2015-05-22 05:41:59       Kate     0    False
     5     2015-05-22 05:37:59       Kate     0    True
```

I want iterate over the `list` , and for each first row of `list` check the value of column `value`, and if it is `False`, delete this row. So the final goal is to delete all the first rows in `list`, that have `False` in `value`
I use this code, that seems logic:

```
def delete_first_false():
    for list, new_df in df.groupby(level=0):
        for index, row in new_df.iterrows():
            new_df=new_df.groupby('name').first().loc([new_df['value']!='False'])
        return new_df
    return df
```

but I have this error

```
AttributeError: '_LocIndexer' object has no attribute 'groupby'
```

could you explain me what's wrong with my method?

Comment: do you mind of i take a stab at revising the title to make it more searchable?

Comment: @PaulH, sure, if you consider it will make more searchable!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your general approach -- using loops -- rarely works the way you want in pandas.

If you have a `groupby` object, you should use the `apply`, `agg`, `filter` or `transform` methods. In your case `apply` is appropriate.

Your main goal is the following:

> So the final goal is to delete all the first rows in (each group defined by 
>   ) `list` that have `False` in (the) `value` (column).

So let's write a simple function to do just that on a single, stand-alone dataframe:

```
def filter_firstrow_falses(df):
    if not df['value'].iloc[0]:
        return df.iloc[1:]
    else:
        return df
```

OK. Simple enough.

Now, let's `apply` that to each group of your real dataframe:

```
import pandas
from io import StringIO

csv = StringIO("""\
list,date_time,name,note,value
1,2015-05-22 05:37:59,Tom,129,False
1,2015-05-22 05:38:59,Tom,0,True
1,2015-05-22 05:39:59,Tom,0,False
1,2015-05-22 05:40:59,Tom,45,True
2,2015-05-22 05:37:59,Kate,129,True
2,2015-05-22 05:41:59,Kate,0,False
2,2015-05-22 05:37:59,Kate,0,True
""")

df = pandas.read_csv(csv)

final = (
    df.groupby(by=['list']) # create the groupby object
      .apply(filter_firstrow_falses) # apply our function to each group
      .reset_index(drop=True) # clean up the index
)
print(final)


   list            date_time  name  note  value
0     1  2015-05-22 05:38:59   Tom     0   True
1     1  2015-05-22 05:39:59   Tom     0  False
2     1  2015-05-22 05:40:59   Tom    45   True
3     2  2015-05-22 05:37:59  Kate   129   True
4     2  2015-05-22 05:41:59  Kate     0  False
5     2  2015-05-22 05:37:59  Kate     0   True
```

Comment: I just test it on my dataframe @PaulH, and maybe because my ```False``` is not boolean value but string, it doesn't delete the first rows that has ```False``` in ```value``` columns

Comment: it's ok, I just change this line ```if not df['value'].iloc[0]:``` of code for  ```if df['value'].iloc[0]=='False'``` and it works! thank you very much for excellent explanation of methods in answer!!