# Writing function to apply to Pandas GroupBy

Tags: python, pandas

Following from this post: [Returning subset of each group from a pandas groupby object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33505339/returning-subset-of-each-group-from-a-pandas-groupby-object)  I'm trying to write a function to apply to a groupby object in pandas

```
def group_by_function(df):
    ID = df.loc[df.Parameter_1==0].Parameter_2.idxmin()        
    df_2 = df.iloc[ID].Parameter

    print(ID)
    return df_2

df.groupby(by=['Column1', 'Column2']).apply(group_by_function)
```

I'm getting a bit lost with how index works in this case. In the example I have the ID returned is 1189 - but the line were I do df.iloc[1189] returns an error that positional indicator is out of bounds.

My understanding was that the index should be preserved during the groupby which is what my ID= line is telling me. But then it's not clear to me why the iloc call is then throwing an error.

My groupby is by two columns - not sure if that's a factor.

Ben

Comment: Can you provide some data so we can elaborate furter...?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `loc` for select by labels, because `idxmin` return indices, not positions:

```
df_2 = df.loc[ID, 'Parameter']
```